# TYPO3 Mask and background image

Tags: typo3, tx-mask, ext-mask

I have used TYPO3 Mask to make an element with a background image. But it looks like that the image is not saved. It is not shown in the frontend.

[image: Backend view of the content element]

Comment: Please provide more information: versions (TYPO3, Mask) and your element definition (DB,TCA,templates). it could help to identify your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you use mask you need to define your own rendering. And that depends on the fields you used in the mask definition (using existing fields and creating new fields).

And the names may change when you exported the mask definition.

And you need to create the additional fields in the database (clear cache and do a database compare, or deactive/reactive the extension).

Then you can look for the field with a `<f:debug title="inside my CE">{_all}</f:debug>` in the rendering template.

Comment: There were nothing in Compare Database. I have tried to add a normal image field and that image is saved without any problems. But the Backgroudn Image field is not saved. If I debug, I get this: background_image => 0 (integer)

Comment: maybe your definition has an error. please add it to your question.

Comment: What is the difference between 'normal' image field and the 'background_image' field in your mask configuration – existing field vs. new custom field? Did you check if the background_image database field exists and if there's a value?

Comment: for new file fields you might miss a fileprocessor.